# debian terminal cannot change to su

Tags: linux, debian, fish

I installed debian strech yesterday. I installed fish shell . I change the default shell to fish by the following

```
su chsh -s 'which fish'
```

Then again enter the this command

```
su chsh -s `which fish`
```

Now after I restart the PC I encountered the following error while using "su"

```
sathish@localhost ~> su
Password: 
Cannot execute which fish: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Okay @jww Thank You

Comment: From unix.stackexchange.com I fix the problem . refereed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374893/debian-9-terminal-cannot-change-to-su/374895?noredirect=1#comment666836_374895)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/374893/4667

Comment: What does `getent passwd root` show?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use regular single-quote chars in your first command? Doing so means your shell is now literally the string `which fish` rather than the path to the fish command. That explains why your second command reports that it cannot execute "which fish". Even without that mistake it is a really bad idea to change the default shell for your root account. You're just asking for trouble. And I say that as a core fish developer. Unless you are an extremely competent and confident CLI user you should not change the root shell. You can always do `exec fish -l` after `su` if you want fish as your root shell.